# PySDL2 issue with SDL_Surface / LP_SDL_Surface

Tags: python, sdl, geometry-surface, pysdl2

Im running win7 with python 3.3 and PySDL2 0.5. When creating surfaces (no matter what method) i get an LP_SDL_Surface instead of a SDL_Surface. The LP_SDL_Surface lacks any of the methods and attribute you would expect it to have. Here is the issue using example code from the [documentation](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/sdl2.html):

```
import os
os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

import sys
import ctypes
from sdl2 import *

def main():
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(b"Hello World",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              592, 460, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)
    windowsurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)

    image = SDL_LoadBMP(b"exampleimage.bmp")
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, None, windowsurface, None)
    print(image.h)

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window)
    SDL_FreeSurface(image)

    running = True
    event = SDL_Event()
    while running:
        while SDL_PollEvent(ctypes.byref(event)) != 0:
            if event.type == SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window)
    SDL_Quit()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

and the traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/.../test.py", line 35, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "C:/.../test.py", line 17, in main
print(image.h)
AttributeError: 'LP_SDL_Surface' object has no attribute 'h'
```

A google search for "LP_SDL_Surface" brings 0 (!) results.

Comment: i have [found out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413851/expected-lp-c-double-instance-instead-of-c-double-array-python-ctypes-error) that LP_* is a ctypes thing and means (long) pointer to *.

realizing this i checked the python ctypes documentation and now use the content attribute to get to the surface itself. so i guess the issue is solved, im still unsure that this is intended behavior though.

Comment: could you please elaborate on your solution? I'm having this issue as well. Using `surface.contents` gives me a null pointer access error.

Comment: sure, or even better, see the explanation i got from Marcus von Appen i got on the sdl forums: http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9419

Comment: @user2697966 you can put it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you work with the lower level SDL methods (e.g. `sdl2.SDL_LoadBMP`) you will have to deal with ctypes conversions, referencing(`byref`) and dereferencing of pointers (`.contents`, `.value`).

So for the specific question, as you've already commented, using `print(image.contents.h)` would be enough.

There are some higher level classes and methods provided by pysdl2 (`sdl2.ext`), however, that could do most of those conversions for you, if desired. The code below achieves the same goal without having to touch ctypes:

```
import os
os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

import sys
import sdl2
import sdl2.ext

def main():
    sdl2.ext.init()
    window = sdl2.ext.Window(
        title="Hello World!", size=(592, 460), flags=sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN,
        position=(sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED))

    window.show()

    renderer = sdl2.ext.Renderer(window)
    factory = sdl2.ext.SpriteFactory(sdl2.ext.TEXTURE, renderer=renderer)
    spriterenderer = factory.create_sprite_render_system(window)

    image = factory.from_image("exampleimage.bmp")
    print(image.size[1])  # image.size = (w, h)

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in sdl2.ext.get_events():
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        spriterenderer.render(image)

    sdl2.ext.quit()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

It also makes use of texture rendering, using hardware acceleration, instead of surface blitting (software based).

Finally, using the higher level `sdl2.ext` you could also instantiate classes (instead of having to write a whole new sprite class yourself) like `sdl2.ext.sprite.TextureSprite`, and implement a `h` property:

```
class TextureSprite(sdl2.ext.TextureSprite):

    @property
    def h(self):
        """The height of the TextureSprite."""
        return self.size[1]

    @property
    def w(self):
        """The width of the TextureSprite."""
        return self.size[0]
```