# ArgumentError:expected LP_c_float instance instead of pointer to LP_c_float_Array_50000

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a function in dll file that takes float pointer as one of argument(argument 9: float *result).

```
void generate_codebook(int *nodestatus, int *nofnode, int *noftree, int *terminal,  int *nofterminal, int *nofobservations, int *total, int *nofseries,  float *result)
```

Here is the python code where I am facing issue:

```
nofseries=c_int(len(nofobservations))
noftree=c_int(terminal.shape[1])
nofnode=c_int(nodestatus.shape[0])
total=c_int(np.sum(nofobservations,dtype=np.int64))
nofentry=ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float *(len(nofobservations)*nofterminal*terminal.shape[1]))()
mydll.generate_codebook.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int),
                                  POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_float)]
result=mydll.generate_codebook(nodestatus.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
                               nofnode,noftree,terminal.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
                               c_int(nofterminal),
                               nofobservations.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),total,
                               nofseries,
                              ctypes.byref(nofentry))
```

While calling generate_codebook function I am facing argument error in last argument where LP_c_float instance is expected. Below is the error:

```
<ipython-input-28-f73a7383211e> in generatecodebook(nodestatus, terminal, nofterminal, nofobservations)
 16                                    nofobservations.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),total,
 17                                    nofseries,
---> 18                                   ctypes.byref(nofentry))

ArgumentError: argument 9: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_float instance instead of pointer to LP_c_float_Array_50000
```

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413851/expected-lp-c-double-instance-instead-of-c-double-array-python-ctypes-error) question's solution but not able to resolve error.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *nofentry* value is a pointer to an array of *float*s, while *generate_codebook* expects a pointer to *float*.
*CTypes* can't do such a conversion automatically, so it has to be performed manually (using [[Python.Docs]: ctypes.cast(obj, type)](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast)).

Example:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes
> >>>
> >>> dim = 100
> >>>
> >>> FloatArr100 = ctypes.c_float * dim
> >>> FloatArr100Ptr = ctypes.POINTER(FloatArr100)
> >>>
> >>> float_arr = FloatArr100(*range(dim))
> >>> float_arr[4], float_arr[38], float_arr[99]
> (4.0, 38.0, 99.0)
> >>>
> >>> float_arr_ptr = ctypes.pointer(float_arr)  # This is the equivalent of your `nofentry`
> >>> float_arr_ptr
> <__main__.LP_c_float_Array_100 object at 0x000001921ED85A48>
> >>> type(float_arr_ptr) is FloatArr100Ptr
> True
> >>>
> >>> float_ptr = ctypes.cast(float_arr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))  # This is what you should do
> >>>
> >>> float_ptr
> <__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x000001921ED859C8>
> >>> float_ptr[4], float_ptr[38], float_ptr[99]
> (4.0, 38.0, 99.0)
> ```

Translated to your code:

1. Change *nofentry* definition to:

   ```py
   nofentry = (ctypes.c_float * (len(nofobservations) * nofterminal * terminal.shape[1]))()  # Notice dropping `ctypes.POINTER`
   ```
2. When invoking *mydll.generate_codebook*, replace

   ```py
   ctypes.byref(nofentry)
   ```

   with

   ```py
   ctypes.cast(nofentry, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
   ```

   so at the end it will look like:

   ```
   result = mydll.generate_codebook(
       nodestatus.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
       nofnode, noftree, terminal.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
       c_int(nofterminal),
       nofobservations.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
       total, nofseries,
       ctypes.cast(nofentry, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)))
   ```

Also mentioning [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Comment: I tried above commands and got ArgumentError: argument 9: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_float instance instead of pointer to LP_c_float

Comment: Hmm, that means that either there's smth wrong in the question, or you didn't do exactly what I've pointed out: `ctypes.cast(nofentry, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))` returns a *LP\_c\_float instance*.

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake while casting but now I get OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000020C7B9F2248

Comment: Unfortunately that info will be only be available in *generate\_codebook* implementation (or docs). The function expects some pointers (that are also arrays) and most likely is trying to access memory outside of he bounds.